# ORA-01001: invalid cursor in a query using the 'for' loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a simple query using cursors, however I keep getting this notorious 'invalid cursor' error. Here's my code.

```
DECLARE
    v_deptno NUMBER := 10;
    c_last_name employees.last_name%TYPE;
    c_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
    c_manager_id employees.salary%TYPE;
    CURSOR c_emp_cursor IS
        SELECT last_name, salary, manager_id FROM employees
        WHERE department_id = v_deptno;
BEGIN
   --OPEN c_emp_cursor;
-- commented out because for loop opens the cursor automatically
    FOR employee IN c_emp_cursor
    LOOP
        FETCH c_emp_cursor INTO c_last_name, c_salary, c_manager_id;
            EXIT WHEN c_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
            IF c_salary < 5000 THEN
                IF c_manager_id = 101 OR c_manager_id = 124 THEN
                    dbms_output.put_line(c_last_name || 'due for a raise.');
                ELSE
                    dbms_output.put_line(c_last_name || ' not due for a raise.');
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END LOOP;
    --CLOSE c_emp_cursor;
END;
```

What could be wrong and what is the solution for this? I have already tried to apply possible solutions for similar questions, but none of them really match my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you commented out `OPEN` and `CLOSE`, you should remove `FETCH` and `EXIT` as well, for the same reason. Furthermore, now you have a cursor variable within the `FOR` statement, so - use it. Something like this:

```
BEGIN
    FOR employee IN c_emp_cursor
    LOOP
            IF employee.salary < 5000 THEN
                IF employee.manager_id = 101 OR employee.manager_id = 124 THEN
                    dbms_output.put_line(employee.last_name || 'due for a raise.');
                ELSE
                    dbms_output.put_line(employee.last_name || ' not due for a raise.');
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```